# merge in doctrine 2 not working giving error

Tags: doctrine-orm, merge

I am trying to update a row in a table. I am using doctrine 2 ORM. I am trying to update a row using `merge()`, which is said can be used to update a row. But it gives a error saying

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

I am new to doctrine 2. please suggest what can i do?

Answer (score 4):

#### When to merge

First off: You only need `$em->merge()` when you have an entity that isn't managed by the EntityManager, but you want it to be. A common use-case is when you have a serialized entity, and want the EntityManager to start managing it.

So merging entities is *not* directly related to updating entities in the database.

If you simply find (using `$repo->find*()`) an entity and make changes, calling `$em-flush()` is sufficient. The entity is already managed by the EntityManager and there's no need to merge it.

#### How to merge

A common mistake when using `$em->merge()` is that the passed entity itself becomes managed. This isn't true, `$em->merge()` returns a *new object* that represents the managed entity.

```
$managedEntity = $em->merge($detachedEntity);
```

After this line of code, `$detachedEntity` is still detached (meaning it still isn't managed by the EntityManager). It's `$managedEntity` which you can start using to make changes.

#### Your code

Given the code you've put in the comments, you probably want to do something like this:

```
$user = $entityManager->getRepository('User')->find($_REQUEST['id']);

$user->setName($_REQUEST['name']);
$user->setPassword($_REQUEST['pass']);

$entityManager->flush();
```

PS: It looks like you're saving the the plain-text password in the database. That's never a good idea.

Comment: I have already done this in the code. But its still not working , giving the same error as before. Here i have given the sample code below.                                                                      $user->setName($_REQUEST['name']);
 $user->setPassword($_REQUEST['pass']);
 $userchk= $entityManager->getRepository('User')->findBy(array('name' => $_REQUEST['name']));
 
 if(count($userchk) == 0)
 {
  // Save in the database
  $entityManager->persist($user);
 }
 else
 { //update in database
  $entityManager->merge($user);
 }
 $entityManager->flush();

Comment: Why do you say you've already done this, when the code you show clearly displays you don't?

Comment: I've updated my answer, in the code you show you don't need to merge.

Comment: I kept missing the part that the merge actually returns a new object. 
This answer helped me, even now I see it's stated in the documentation, it's easily missed.